# Xbox One to Windows 10 streaming quality

Tags: xbox-one, streaming

Okay so a while ago I asked a question about how to stream Xbox One gameplay to a Windows 10 computer

Now there is an option to change the stream quality, although I'm wondering does the streams quality rely on your internet's connection speed i.e. upload/download or does it rely on your local area network speed i.e. how fast your hub/router can upload/download at

I'm unsure because I know your Xbox One and the Windows 10 PC have to be on the same network.

Comment: I doubt it has to do with internet speed as you aren't leaving your home network, I always thought it was your network strength to your router in combination with your PC's performance (to be able to decode the stream and such), but I am unsure, so no answer.

Comment: Like @Rapitor is saying,  its most likely relys on your LAN speeds. Your router is the sole most important factor in the equation. Although, preferably you would be streaming with both devices plugged into the router via ethernet cables. This is how you'd achieve the greatest quality without lag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming from an Xbox One to a Windows 10 PC will be heavily dependant on the quality of your local network, whether that be via ethernet or WiFi, and the quality of the experience will be largely down to latency.

The latency and quality of signal when using WiFi is dependant on the environment - that is, quality of walls, other WiFi networks in the same area, etc, so if you're having issues it might be worth re-testing with a wired connection.

Comment: Its also very dependant on your computer hardware. Lower specced machines with the same wifi card lag considerably more then high-end machines

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior at all, especially with Steam streaming - playing games that just can't run on hardware that barely runs Windows with sufficient FPS and responsiveness to play the game

Comment: Steam is not an xbox. I use this feature a fair bit, both pre beta and now its been released. For an xbox, it makes a pretty big differance. I have both a low spec and a high spec, and one is limited to low quality, while the other supports high